# Python import csv to list, split after last double double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a CSV file which is export from SQL database. Now the problem is that the last field in the table contains many lines. I have a problem importing it to list. How can I import CSV file to list so the last item in list will be the last column content with all of its lines. (multiple item with new lines supposed to be in one field list)

CSV File content:

```
`1,Policy,02/07/2018 11:57:39,Inbound Files,,False,";Facet Advanced:Advanced
StrPropType_FileSizeByTypeLimit=
StrPropType_ServerPort=11073
NumPropType_CheckServerCertificate=False
NumPropType_ResumeSanitizationsOnReconnect=True
NumPropType_KeepAliveSec=60
StrPropType_SyslogServer=
NumPropType_ResultsFormat=0`
```

When the first 8 columns is the following

```
`1,Policy,02/07/2018 11:57:39,Inbound Files,,False,`
```

The rest is one field only in database, so I need to have it in a separate item in list.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: @rukhta 

 with open(full_file_path, newline='\n') as f:
            for i, x in enumerate(f)

But it doesnt do it right.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the last quote isn't actually missing and your csv file is correct – just use `csv.reader`. It'll handle the newlines correctly:

```
>>> for line in csv.reader(open('...')):
...     print(repr(line))
... 
['1', 'Policy', '02/07/2018 11:57:39', 'Inbound Files', '', 'False', ';Facet Advanced:Advanced\nStrPropType_FileSizeByTypeLimit=\nStrPropType_ServerPort=11073\nNumPropType_CheckServerCertificate=False\nNumPropType_ResumeSanitizationsOnReconnect=True\nNumPropType_KeepAliveSec=60\nStrPropType_SyslogServer=\nNumPropType_ResultsFormat=0']
```

Answer (score 1):

if your csv has the correct quoting you can load it in a dataframe:

input:

```
1,Policy,02/07/2018 11:57:39,Inbound Files,,False,";Facet Advanced:Advanced
StrPropType_FileSizeByTypeLimit=
StrPropType_ServerPort=11073
NumPropType_CheckServerCertificate=False
NumPropType_ResumeSanitizationsOnReconnect=True
NumPropType_KeepAliveSec=60
StrPropType_SyslogServer=
NumPropType_ResultsFormat=0"
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_table('data2',engine='python',sep=',',header=None)
print(a)
```

output:

```
   0       1                    2              3   4      5  \
0  1  Policy  02/07/2018 11:57:39  Inbound Files NaN  False   

                                                   6  
0  ;Facet Advanced:Advanced\nStrPropType_FileSize...
```